# Laravel - How to apply Laravel old() helper function on dynamic input form

Tags: laravel, validation

In Laravel-5.8 project, I am working on dynamic input form.

The main model is AppraisalGoal while the second model is AppraisalGoalDetail

Controller

```
public function create()
{
     $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
     $goaldetail    =   new    AppraisalGoalDetail();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.create')
            ->with('goal', $goal)  
    ->with('goaldetail', $goaldetail) ;
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try {
        $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;

             if ($request->appraisal_doc != "") {
                 $appraisal_doc = $request->file('appraisal_doc');
                 $new_name = rand() . '.' . $appraisal_doc->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $appraisal_doc->move(public_path('storage/documents/appraisal_goal'), $new_name);
                 $goal->appraisal_doc = $new_name;
            }  
         $goal->save(); 

        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
            $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date[$key]);
            $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date[$key]);

$insert_array = [
            'kpi_description'            => $request->kpi_description[$key],
            'activity'                   => $request->activity[$key], 
            'start_date'                 => $startDate ->toDateTimeString(),
            'end_date'                   => $endDate->toDateTimeString(),                
        ];

AppraisalGoalDetail::create($insert_array );
         }
    DB::commit(); 

            Session::flash('success', 'Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route(goals.index');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {

DB::rollback();
            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->route('goals.index');
    }
}
```

the create.blade view is shown below

```
   <form  action="{{route('goals.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>                 
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" value="{{ old('goal_title', $goal->goal_title) }}" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>      

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" value="{{old('goal_description',$goal->goal_description)}}" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ...">{{old('goal_description',$goal->goal_description)}}</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

   <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Activity<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">KPI<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Start Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">End Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="btn btn-info addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi_description" ></td>
                            <td><input type="date" class="form-control start_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="start_date[]"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" class="form-control end_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="end_date[]"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}"></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight(%):<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control" max="120">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"> Attachment:</label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input value="{{old('appraisal_doc',$goal->appraisal_doc)}}" type="file" name="appraisal_doc" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
    </div>           

    </form>
```

AppraisalGoal is foreignkey to AppraisalGoalDetail. AppraisalGoalDetail is an Array.

The way the application operates is that, When the user clicks the submit button,  the application saves into AppraisalGoal and pick its id and saves it with the other data into AppraisalGoalDetail.

However, the validation is giving issue. Whenever the user submits and the page is validated, all went blank upon showing the error page, meaning that I need to input them all over again.

I was able to resolve these ones that belong to AppraisalGoal model by using old() help function and it works:

```
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>                 
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" value="{{ old('goal_title', $goal->goal_title) }}" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>      

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" value="{{old('goal_description',$goal->goal_description)}}" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ...">{{old('goal_description',$goal->goal_description)}}</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I don't know how to resolve these ones that belong to AppraisalGoalDetail:

```
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi_description" ></td>
                            <td><input type="date" class="form-control start_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="start_date[]"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" class="form-control end_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="end_date[]"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}"></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
```

How do I get this corrected that the page should still retain the data after submit and validation error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When You get Validation Error & something fault in server..You redirect the page & withInput() function like this..

```
return redirect()->route('goals.index')->withInput(['goal_title' => $request->goal_title, 'goal_description' => $request->goal_description]);
```

It will sork & show your value which you give to update

Comment: How about this?           foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
            $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date[$key]);
            $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date[$key]);

$insert_array = [
            'kpi_description'            => $request->kpi_description[$key],
            'activity'                   => $request->activity[$key], 
            'start_date'                 => $startDate ->toDateTimeString(),
            'end_date'                   => $endDate->toDateTimeString(),                
        ];